# VB6 For Loop not accepted in one function, works fine in another

Tags: vb6, foreach, activex

I have an old ActiveX Component written in VB6 to support (don't even bother asking to modernize it, that's just what I have currently) and it does some weird stuff when compiling the following code:

```
Dim connectedPrinter As printer
Dim printers() As String

For Each connectedPrinter In printers
    printers(UBound(printers)) = connectedPrinter.DeviceName
Next
```

All it should do is make a list of all connected printers. But, when compiling, VB6 tells me that

> For Each control variable on arrays must be Variant

What's odd about that is, that in another function of the **same** codebase, I use the exact same loop for a different task (setting the current printer als default)

```
Dim pPrinter As printer

For Each pPrinter In printers
    If (pPrinter.DeviceName = sPrinterName) Then
        Set printer = pPrinter
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Yet, that is accepted without hesitation, compiles and also demonstrably works in the production environment.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the problem snippet, you have a local array called `printers` hiding the `Printers` collection. You can rename the local array, or qualify access to the collection by referring to it as `VB.Printers`.

Comment: Such a silly error... I guess it's true to say "not seeing the wood for the trees"... Thanks!

Comment: not seeing the forest for the trees, or not seeing the whole for its parts.